# Solving $\sec^2 x+ \tan^2 x = 1$ over the interval $[0,2\pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

I keep trying to solve

$$\sec^2 x+ \tan^2 x = 1$$

I notice that $\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x$ so I tried substituting $\sec^2 x$ with $\tan^2 x + 1$.

I get $$\tan^2 x + 1 + \tan^2 x = 1 \tag{1}$$

Then I try to solve by using the zero product property, so I subtract 1 from the right side of the equation.

Leaving me with $$\tan^2 x+ \tan^2 x = 0 \tag{2}$$

I add and divide both sides by two leaving me with
$$\tan^2 x = 0 \tag{3}$$

Thinking I was right, I thought the answer was $\left\{\dfrac{\pi}{2} , \dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right\}$, but that was wrong.

Comment: Everything up to the very end is correct. $\tan\frac\pi 2\neq0$.

Answer (score 1):

if you take the square root of both sides, tan^2(x) = 0 becomes tan(x) = 0. The answer to this is {0, pi}.

You can check this because tan(x) is sin(x)/cos(x), so for tan(x) to be zero sin(x) must be zero. This occurs at the two values listed above.

Most of your process was correct, you just simplified wrong at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity: $1+\text{tan}^2(\theta)=\text{sec}^2(\theta) \Rightarrow \text{tan}^2(\theta)=\text{sec}^2(\theta) -1$
$$\sec^2(\theta)+ \tan^2(\theta) = 1$$
$$\sec^2(\theta)+ \sec^2(\theta)-1 = 1$$
$$2\sec^2(\theta)=2  $$
$$\sec(\theta)=\pm 1 $$
Once the interval given is $[0, 2\pi)$, the solution is $\theta=\{0, \pi\}$

Note that the identity is only true when $\theta \neq \frac{\pi}{2}$.
$$\sec^2\theta-\tan^2\theta=1; |\sec\theta|\geq1$$
$$\forall\;\theta\in\mathbb{R}-\{(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}, n\in\mathbb{Z} \}$$